# how to inscribe the phd book when handing in it to the advisor

Tags: phd, thesis

I'm going to hand in a copy of my phd book to my supervisor. 
I think normally people write a small note by hand on the first page to somehow acknowledge their advisor (even though he has been already acknowledged in the "acknowledgment" section). 
What is a suitable note to write for him? 
Thanks

Comment: This should be something personal to express your thanks and gratitude. Even if we knew you and your supervisor (which we don't), we couldn't write this for you. This note shouldn't be generic (except maybe if you didn't have a good relationship).

Comment: That's true. I just wanted to know some examples. How to begin.

Comment: Remember the good times, e.g., how they welcomed you in the working group or how they motivated you after your experiments all seemed to fail or the nice stories they told you over a beer during the evenings when you traveled together ... Then just write something heartfelt.

Comment: "I think normally people write a small note": not so normally ;-) Some do, some don't.

Comment: Why don't you look at some other theses in your area?